# is there any way or package in flutter let me display specific app screen in my device home

Tags: flutter, dart

say my app is running in foreground and I press my device home button and my app go to the background and there is services running in my app that listening to specific event to occur in order to start new screen ... my question is how can I let that new screen to be displayed in my device home just like coming call screen although my app is running in background ....
I want the screen to lunch like taxi booking app for driver when new request is coming so how to do that by flutter

Comment: You can't force the app to come back to foreground. The user must click something. It's a security design.

Comment: I want the screen to lunch like taxi booking app for driver when new request is coming

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't do that in Flutter, anyway not in any cross-platform way as Apple does not allow that.
Your best bet would be to send a notification that the user presses and which in turn will open the app.
If that something you would consider ?